# IOS: How discriminate automatic startup or user launch of the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, startup

In an iPhone application (iOS v4.2 or higher):

I need to discriminate whether the application was opened by the user from phone (by clicking on the application icon from the desktop phone) or was executed automatically at system startup.

I have read and searched exhaustively but have not found the answer to this case.

Thank you!

Comment: When are applications ever executed automatically at startup?

Comment: What do you mean by "executed automatically at system startup"?  When someone unlocks their phone?

Comment: Hi Richard. Yes, when the phone is turned on.

Comment: No 3rd party apps are automatically started when the phone is turned on

Comment: Hi Paul. Yes, the VOIP apps. (BACKGROUD MODE in the info.plist)

Comment: That allows your app to run in the background, that does not mean that it is automatically launched at System startup.

Comment: Yes, see this [link](https://github.com/lithium3141/BootLaunch)

Answer (score 1):

You can determine this by interrogating the launch options passed into willFinishLaunchingWithOptions. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> If your application was launched by the system for a specific reason, the launchOptions dictionary contains data indicating the reason for the launch. Your app should look in this dictionary for any keys that correspond to features your app supports. If the given key is present, you should provide an appropriate response.
>
> If your app was launched to open a URL, you should examine the value of the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey key and return a Boolean value indicating whether your app can actually open the URL. You should not try to open the URL in this method. Instead, implement the application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method in your app delegate and use that method to open the URL.

Comment: Ok, I use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for IOS 4.3 and launchOptions is nil in both cases (autostart or user launch) -